# How to cast a double value to a integer value in UPPAAL?

Tags: uppaal

How it is possible to cast a double value to a integer value in uppaal?

```
double rand;
rand = random(2);
int i;
i = (int) rand;
```

According to the API documentation (http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/help.php?file=System_Descriptions/Expressions.shtml) following function is available, but it is not working:

```
int fint(double x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fint function is implemented in 4.1.20, please download it.

Comment: I am running 4.1.20 beta3 (1) on Mac 64 bit OS. It says Unknown identifier fint when I try to use it. Can you help?

Comment: @MrDank beta versions are earlier than 4.1.20 final release so it probably does not have it. Could you try the newest 4.1.23?